# How to format DATE in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, biztalk, xslt-1.0

I searched a bit but couldn't find the answer.

I want to get current date and format to `YYYYMMDD`

I cannot use EXSLT as per my requirements.

Comment: And you already have such information? Current date is not part of XSLT 1.0 context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple Inline C# Script Functoid could look like this:

```
public string MyDateFormat(string dateValue)
{
    string result = String.Empty;
    string outputFormat = "{0:yyyyMMdd}";

    DateTime parsed;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateValue, out parsed))
    {
        result = String.Format(outputFormat, parsed);
    }
    else
    {
        result = String.Format(outputFormat, DateTime.MinValue);
    }

    return result;
}
```

For a similar problem I created a External Assembly which will allow to specify `CultureInfo` for parsing the input DateTime string and also submit the output format string as a functoid input parameter.

Comment: Yes i used similar C# functoid to return  the date and connected it to another scripting functoid where i used the Inline XSLT Call Template to achieve this

Answer (score -1):

You want the substring to act on the date.

To get the date:

```
substring-before($dateTime, 'T')
```

To get the year you want to work on the above result:

```
substring-before($previousResult, '-')
```

Then concatenate the values you got from the string manipulations.

This explains the whole thing and wraps it on a template: [Format a date in XML via XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500915/format-a-date-in-xml-via-xslt)

etc

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do i need to set some value for $dateTime?

Comment: @KK, you can pass date as an external stylesheet parameter. There is no way to get current date with the help of functions specified in the xpath 1.0 stadard. If you're using 2.0 then you can use `fn:current-time()`, `fn:current-date()`, `fn:current-dateTime()`.

Comment: Yes but I use the XSLT in BizTalk

Comment: @Karthik Is your BizTalk Map XSLT-only? Is it a requirement to use XSLT instead of a Functiod to transform the date value?