# Convert timestamp to date with XSLT

Tags: xslt, date, timestamp

I have node like:

```
<item id="37" publish_time="1293829200">
```

How to convert @publish_time to date like **dd.mm.yyyy**?

I'm using libxslt

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format DATE in XSLT 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309370/how-to-format-date-in-xslt-1-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a template that I wrote to convert seconds to a more readable format. You can extend it to cover your needs :

```
<xsl:template name="convertSecsToTimeStamp">
            <xsl:param name="seconds"/> 
            <xsl:variable name="hours" select="floor($seconds div (60 * 60))"/>
            <xsl:variable name="divisor_for_minutes" select="$seconds mod (60 * 60)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="floor($divisor_for_minutes div 60)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="divisor_for_seconds" select="$divisor_for_minutes mod 60"/>
            <xsl:variable name="secs" select="ceiling($divisor_for_seconds)"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$hours &lt; 10">
                    <xsl:text>0</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$hours"/><xsl:text>hh</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$hours"/><xsl:text>hh</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$minutes &lt; 10">
                    <xsl:text>0</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$minutes"/><xsl:text>mm</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$minutes"/><xsl:text>mm</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$secs &lt; 10">
                    <xsl:text>0</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$secs"/><xsl:text>ss</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$secs"/><xsl:text>ss</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
```