# Custom DateTime formats when using DataSet.WriteXml in .NET

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, dataset

I've got an issue where I am writing a DataSet to XML that has a column of type DateTime and I want to control the output format.

```
DataSet data = LoadDataSet();
data.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MyDate"] = DateTime.Now;
data.WriteXml(myFile);
```

By default the format of the DateTime in the XML seems to be as follows:

```
2011-08-02T17:39:00-07:00
```

I'd like use a custom date format, or at the very least strip the timezone info.

Is there any way to control the format of the DateTime columns in my dataset XML?

My gut says no since I am assuming it is done this way to facilitate conversion of data across time zones but I've noticed that I can successfully read DataSet XML even if DateTime column tags omit the timezone data so I was hoping I can do something analogous when writing to XML.

Comment: I've seen some developers use tricks like adding another column called ["MyDateString"] where they use DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() , not saying thats ideal, but I've seen it first hand in serialization classes for some messages we exchange with other partners :)

Comment: Yeah, I just mentioned that to a colleague. That will probably be our fallback plan.

Comment: Can you define XSLT schema and apply it to XML, or is it would be an overkill in your case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is one standard format for `DateTime` in XML. That's the format that `WriteXml` will use. If you need a different format, then you need to not use `DateTime`. As others have said, use `String` instead.

Comment: That's a gray area, there is no schema reference in the generated files so nothing explicitly forces the DateTime tags from WriteXml to be of type xsd:date.  I'd agree that xsd:date has a strict format, but I'm not sure that is necessarily in use here.

Comment: Your idea would require that `WriteXml` generate data in a format that the schema from `WriteXmlSchema` would not validate. That seems unlikely.

Answer (score 12):

This workaround might suit if you can live with just the timezone info getting stripped out. The default for the DateTimeMode property of DateTime columns in DataSets is UnspecifiedLocal. You could explicitly set the DateTimeMode to Unspecified, which means that the timezone part does not get serialized.

e.g.

You can use a function like this :

```
    public static void RemoveTimezoneForDataSet(DataSet ds)
    {
        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {

                if (dc.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    dc.DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Unspecified;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Example of usage :

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("t1");
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("DT", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, new DateTime(2009, 1, 1) });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, new DateTime(2010, 12, 23) });

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    ds.WriteXml("c:\\Standard.xml");

    RemoveTimezoneForDataSet(ds);

    ds.WriteXml("c:\\WithoutTimezone.xml");
```

Output :

Standard.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <t1>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <DT>2009-01-01T00:00:00+11:00</DT>
  </t1>
  <t1>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <DT>2010-12-23T00:00:00+11:00</DT>
  </t1>
</NewDataSet>
```

WithoutTimezone.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <t1>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <DT>2009-01-01T00:00:00</DT>
  </t1>
  <t1>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <DT>2010-12-23T00:00:00</DT>
  </t1>
</NewDataSet>
```

If you don't like the idea of modifying the DataColumns of your original DataSet, you could make a copy of it, then call the function on the copy.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  It would seem only DataSetDateTime.Unspecified will work because I get an error message trying to use LocalTime - mode can't be changed if the table already has data.

Answer (score 1):

Apply XSLT transformation to DataSet: (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fd7xytc.aspx))
(I believe you will find XSLT example to convert DateTime format, or see [post on SO regarding XSLT and DateTIme formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500915/format-a-date-in-xml-via-xslt))

```
DataSet custDS = new DataSet("CustomerDataSet");
XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument(custDS); 

XslTransform xslTran = new XslTransform();
xslTran.Load("transform.xsl");

XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("xslt_output.html", 
  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

xslTran.Transform(xmlDoc, null, writer);
writer.Close();
```

Comment: we're actually transforming it via XSLT after the fact already (for integration with a third party system), but the output format cares about AM/PM so for now we're just writing conditional XSLT logic to parse the 24-hr date format and turn it into a 12-hr AM/PM format.  Kind of messy but it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty but simple solution to convert datatime to string :

```
select concat(datetime_field,'') datetime_field from table_name
```

Answer (score -1):

If the file is regular, and the exported XML seems so, you can just rewrite it using simple loop. Easy and quick solution. Use some of my code if you want:

```
private void rewriteXML(string oldFile, string newFile, int startPos, int strLength)
        {
            try
            {
                File.Delete(newFile);
            }
            catch { Console.WriteLine("File didn't existed."); }
            StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(oldFile);
            string data;
            StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(newFile);
            while ((data = SR.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (data.Contains("<start>"))
                {
                    string ln_tmp = data.Replace(" ", "");
                    string newline = "    <start>" + ln_tmp.Substring(startPos, strLength) + "</start>";
                    SW.WriteLine(newline);
                }
                else
                    SW.WriteLine(data);
            }
            SR.Close();
            SW.Close();
        }
```

The output is like:

```
<start>19:34</start>
```

Instead of:

```
<start>2013-03-17T19:34:00+01:00</start>
```

Comment: Code doesn't implement `using` blocks, and that try/catch block will hide exceptions other than file not found.