# I want to change the format of DateTime field inside DataSet

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have dataset with a table Temp, and i want to change the format of a DateTime field. Is there any direct method to do that.

myDataSet->Tables->Item["Temp"]->Columns->Item["DateTimeColumnName"]

this is the column, Temp is the table and how can i achieve this? i want to do it in Ado.net.

Comment: When you say "change the format", you mean setting the right string displayed on the UI ?

Comment: I wants to store it as an xml file. Now In xml the format is like 2014-04-22T09:37:18+05:30, i wants to change this to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss.

Comment: Possible duplicate with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932071/custom-datetime-formats-when-using-dataset-writexml-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
foreach (DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows) 
{
    row["UrDateColumn"]= DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0}:dd-MM-yyyy",dr["UrDateColumn"]));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i dont want to change the data type, i already have a DateTime type column. i want to change the format of date. i need to store the entire data into an xml file. The format of Datetime field in xml is like 2014-04-22T09:37:18+05:30 but i wants this as mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss.

Comment: what is the problem with following code, in C++.Net

Comment: mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(S"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=myDb;User Id=user;Password=pw;"); mySQLConnection->Open();
myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(S"select * from Scheduler",mySQLConnection); myDataSet = new DataSet("labops");
myDataAdapter->FillSchema(myDataSet,SchemaType::Mapped, "Temp");
myDataAdapter->Fill (myDataSet,"Temp");
dt = myDataSet->Tables->Item["Temp"];

mySQLConnection->Close();

Comment: myDataSet = new DataSet("labops");
myDataAdapter->FillSchema(myDataSet,SchemaType::Mapped, "Temp");
myDataAdapter->Fill (myDataSet,"Temp");
dt = myDataSet->Tables->Item["Temp"];
for(int i=0; i<dt->Rows->Count; i++){
 dt->Rows->get_Item(i)->set_Item("Exercise_Start_Time",DateTime::Parse(String::Format("{0}:dd-MM-yyyy",dt->Rows->get_Item(i)->get_Item("Exercise_Start_Time"))));
 
}

dt->WriteXml("G:/data.xml");

Comment: date time will change to the above format while coverting to XML.
If you uses an XSLT create a function to format date

or find below link http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/153810/How-to-change-Dateformat-in-Xml-while-converting-d