# The string '01/06/2015' is not a valid AllXsd value

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, xsd, dataset

I am getting this error

> The string '01/06/2015' is not a valid AllXsd value

My XSD is:

```
<xs:element name="PassingDate">
                <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
                <xs:pattern value="\d{2}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{4}"></xs:pattern>
                </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
```

I am reading my XML into a `DataSet` and then I have to perform **sorting** on the basis of `PassingDate`.

If I will now convert `PassingDate` into dataType date, then sorting will be done on the basis of string only. Which will lead to wrong output.

How to format date in `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PassingDate` declaration doesn't rearrange the components of a date -- it just further restricts those components in their original places.

You can switch to purely regex constraints to get close:

```
<xs:element name="PassingDate">
  <xs:simpleType name="date">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9]{4}" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

**Notes:**

1. This approach doesn't fully prevent invalid dates that have too many days
   for a given month, leap/non-leap years, etc.
2. `YYYY-MM-DD` is better for international exchange.
3. `YYYY-MM-DD` is better for interoperability
4. `YYYY-MM-DD` is better for sorting.

**Recommendation**: Use standard `type="xs:date"` for your XML and localize the date format for data entry/display only.  If you're stuck with XML that uses a non-standard date format, investigate pre/post-processing or write custom code.  You might get some ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932071/custom-datetime-formats-when-using-dataset-writexml-in-net).

Comment: Hi, I have used your xsd, but when i am applying sorting it is not sorting my column in Datatable. Because in your xsd we are not setting DataType of the column "PassingDate". How to set it as type=date with dd/MM/yyyy format in xsd?

Comment: Use `xs:date` as-is and `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: its a requirement as i am getting an xml, in and in order to apply sorting in datatable i need to set there dataType so i used xsd. But now i am stuck over here with date only. help

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to preprocess or write custom code then.