# XML Date Formatting using xsl

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have a XML document. I am getting date from XML in this '2011-08-01' format. 
I have to display the same date using either Java Script or XSL in 'August 08th,2011' format. 
The XML tag is like this:
`<DatelineDate>2011-08-01</DatelineDate>`
Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 1.0 is not a great technology for date formatting. You either have to do this manually with string processing, or via some XSLT parser specific extensions, for example the microsoft [ms:format-date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256099.aspx) function. However, XSLT 2.0 does have the format-date as standard.

I would recommend using JavaScript instead. See this related question:

[Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: ColinE: Absolute statements are almost always wrong. Your statement starting with "XSLT is not a great technology ..." isn't correct in the case of any version of XSLT greater than one. Please, edit and correct.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - updated to clarify. However, based on the question given, I would still choose JavaScript for simplicity and portability.

Comment: ColinE: Great. As for personal preferences, the OP obviously is interested in an XSLT solution.

Comment: @Dimitre the OP is interested in both, and related questions on SO indicate that many believe XSLT 1.0 is not great for date formatting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500915/format-a-date-in-xml-via-xslt

Comment: ColinE: The author has specified "XSLT" -- not just "XSLT 1.0".

Comment: @Dimitre sure, however I stand by my remark that *in general* (i.e. in the lack of further information) JavaScript is a better bet. This does not mean to say I have anything against XSLT, it is a great technology, one which I have used on numerous occasions. However, picking an appropriate technology for a problem, when you are faced with a choice, is an important decision.

Comment: ColinE: I understand your argument, however, *in general* a person isn't supposed and maynot be using Javascript. These are personal preferences and while I fully respect your own, different people have the right to have different preferences. A good answer doesn't try to impose its author's personal preferences by saying "Technology A is better than technology B". A good answer will just provide solutions (in one or more technologies) and will leave it to the asking person to decide based on his own personal preferences.

Answer (score 1):

**I. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="DatelineDate">
     <xsl:sequence select="format-date(xs:date(.), '[MNn] [D1o], [Y]')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<DatelineDate>2011-08-01</DatelineDate>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
August 1st, 2011
```

**Note**: Saxon CE makes XSLT 2.0 available in the five major browsers.

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

This is a simple and understandable solution, that doesn't rely on tricks and unreadable, hardcoded offsets.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:months>
  <m num="1">January</m>
  <m num="2">February</m>
  <m num="3">March</m>
  <m num="4">April</m>
  <m num="5">May</m>
  <m num="6">June</m>
  <m num="7">July</m>
  <m num="8">August</m>
  <m num="9">September</m>
  <m num="10">October</m>
  <m num="11">November</m>
  <m num="12">December</m>
 </my:months>

 <xsl:variable name="vMonthNames" select=
  "document('')/*/my:months/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="DatelineDate">
   <xsl:variable name="vYear"
        select="substring-before(., '-')"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vdMonth" select=
    "substring-before(substring-after(., '-'), '-')"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vdDay" select=
    "substring-after(substring-after(., '-'), '-')"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vMonthName" select=
     "$vMonthNames[@num = number($vdMonth)]"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vordDaySuffix">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=
       "$vdDay mod 10 = 1
       and
        not($vdDay = 11)">st</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$vdDay mod 10 = 2">nd</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$vdDay mod 10 = 3">rd</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>th</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat($vMonthName,
             ' ',
             $vdDay, $vordDaySuffix,
             ', ',
             $vYear
             )
     "/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
August 01st, 2011
```

Comment: The XSLT 1.0 solution in this answer produces incorrect results for some dates.

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed it would be obvious. I could tell at a glance that `August 11st, 2011` probably wouldn't be acceptable.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Thanks. Please, accept that not all people are native English speakers, so such linguistic peculiarities aren't obvious. I edited my answer to account for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these links:

1. http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#date-time-examples, and
2. [ms:format_date function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256099.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple template I use in XSLT 1.0 sometimes

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="months" select="'January  February March    April    May      June     July     August   SeptemberOctober  December '" />
 <xsl:variable name="dayord" select="'-stndrdthththththththththththththththththstndrdthththththththst'" />

 <xsl:template match="DatelineDate">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(
    substring($months,substring(.,6,2) * 9 - 8, 8),
    ' ',
    substring(.,9,2) + 0,
    substring($dayord,substring(.,9,2)*2,2),
    ', ',
    substring(.,1,4)
   ))" />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The substrings are a little convoluted, but they basically pick out the appropriate month name and date suffix from two variables. NB: The spacing in those variables is important, the month names MUST be 9 characters apart. The `+0` on the 3rd line of that concat is just a simple trick to treat it as a number rather than the text `01`; Leave that out if you actually prefer the `01` formatting.