# formatting non static date string XSLT XML

Tags: xml, string, xslt

My XML has a date string which looks likes this

```
<row id="1">
  <DocDueDate>12/06/2016 12:00:00 AM</DocDueDate>
</row>
```

I am trying to format it using XSLT

```
<shipdate>
    <!--YYYY-DD-MM-->
    <xsl:variable name="var_shipdate" select="row/DocDueDate" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($var_shipdate, 7, 4), '-', substring($var_shipdate, 1, 2), '-', substring($var_shipdate, 4, 2) ) " />
</shipdate>
```

This produces an output like this

```
<shipdate>
20161206           
</shipdate>
```

Buy my string concatenation fails in the xslt and produces a wrong output if my date format changes from `MM/DD/YYYY` to `MM/D/YYYY` or `M/D/YYYY` or `M/DD/YYYY`

So how do I manipulate my string concatenation to produce an output like `YYYYMMDD`
irrespective of my source xml format.. 
I need to pad it with zeros but how do i split my source string on '/'

Comment: For a possible solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500915/format-a-date-in-xml-via-xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<shipdate>
    <!--YYYY-DD-MM-->
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before(row/DocDueDate, ' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-after(substring-after($date, '/'), '/')" />
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before($date, '/')" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-before(substring-after($date, '/'), '/')" />

    <xsl:value-of select="$year" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($month, '-00')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($day, '-00')" />
</shipdate>
```