# Convert date string coming as(Day,Month Day,Year -time) format from xml to date format in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I convert the string date "Wednesday, April 25, 2018 - 11:00" coming from input xml to 2018-04-25 11:00 AM format in my xslt code.

following is the input xml which is coming from RSS feed and cant be changed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xml:base="https://www.hhs.gov/rss/news.xml" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>Latest News Releases</title>
        <link>https://www.hhs.gov/rss/news.xml</link>
        <description>HHS News Releases</description>
        <language>en</language>
        <atom:link href="https://www.hhs.gov/rss/news.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <item>
            <title>Secretary Azar, Surgeon General Adams Praise Private Sector Support for Naloxone Advisory</title>
            <link>https://www.hhs.gov/about/news/2018/04/25/secretary-azar-surgeon-general-adams-praise-private-sector-support-naloxone-advisory.html</link>
            <description>&lt;p&gt;Following the early April release of the Surgeon General’s Advisory on Naloxone and Opioid Overdose
            </description>
            <pubDate>Wednesday, April 25, 2018 - 11:00</pubDate>
            <dc:creator>HHS Press Office</dc:creator>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">https://www.hhs.gov/about/news/2018/04/25/secretary-azar-surgeon-general-adams-praise-private-sector-support-naloxone-advisory.html</guid>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Here is the XSL I have written

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"

    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/rss">
        <Records>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="channel/item" /> 
        </Records>

    </xsl:template>      

    <xsl:template match="channel/item">
        <xsl:element name="Record">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="*">        
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output i am getting is below. Notice the date is coming as string which is causing my feed to fail. How can I convert the string date "Wednesday, April 25, 2018 - 11:00" to 2018-04-25 11:00 AM format

```
<Record>
            <title>Secretary Azar, Surgeon General Adams Praise Private Sector Support for Naloxone Advisory</title>
            <link>https://www.hhs.gov/about/news/2018/04/25/secretary-azar-surgeon-general-adams-praise-private-sector-support-naloxone-advisory.html</link>
            <description>&lt;p&gt;Following the early April release of the Surgeon General’s Advisory on Naloxone and Opioid Overdose
            </description>
            <pubDate>Wednesday, April 25, 2018 - 11:00</pubDate>
            <creator>HHS Press Office</creator>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">https://www.hhs.gov/about/news/2018/04/25/secretary-azar-surgeon-general-adams-praise-private-sector-support-naloxone-advisory.html</guid>
        </Record>
```

Comment: Maybe [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500915/1305969) will inspire you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have access to the MSXSL namespace, you can add a script extension to your XSL stylesheet that does the date conversion in a more suitable programming language (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970889(v=vs.85).aspx)).

For the sake of the example, let's use JScript, but using .NET languages in the script block is also possible (see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-stylesheet-scripting-using-msxsl-script)).

The following uses an `<msxsl:script>` block to define a `convertDate()` function, which will later be usable in your XSLT code with a prefix. It converts valid dates in this format `"Wednesday, April 25, 2018 - 11:00"` to `"2018-04-25 11:00"`. Anything it cannot convert, it returns unchanged.

`<msxsl:script>` is allowed on the same level where your `<xsl:template>` elements are.

```
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="script">
<![CDATA[

// converts dates like this one: "Wednesday, April 25, 2018 - 11:00"
// to "2018-04-25 11:00"
function convertDate(text) {
    var m = text.match(/[a-z]+, ([a-z]+) (\d{1,2}), (\d{4}) - (\d\d:\d\d)/i),
        zero = function (s) { return ('0' + s).slice(-2); },
        dateStr, date;

    if (m) {
        dateStr = [m[2], m[1], m[3], m[4]].join(' ');
        date = new Date(Date.parse(dateStr));
        if (date) {
            return [
                date.getFullYear(),
                '-',
                zero(date.getMonth() + 1),
                '-',
                zero(date.getDate()),
                ' ',
                zero(date.getHours()),
                ':',
                zero(date.getMinutes())
            ].join('');
        }
    }
    return text;
}

]]>
</msxsl:script>

<xsl:template match="pubDate">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="script:convertDate(.)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is there any built in function in xslt 2.0 or 3.0 which does this?

Comment: You have regex- and date-related functions in XSLT 2.0+, related thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575111/can-an-xslt-insert-the-current-date. The stylesheet you show uses XSLT 1.0 specifically, so I assumed that nothing else was available to you.

Comment: XPath 3.1 has the function parse-ietf-date()