# XSLT 1.0 (xsltproc) - Convert date format from yyyy-mm-ddthh-mm-ssz to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z

Tags: date, xslt, xslt-1.0

Input XML:

```
<testng-results>
<suite>
<test>
    <class>
        <test-method name="ABC" started-at="2019-03-13T21:26:52Z"></test-method>
        <test-method name="XYZ" started-at="2019-03-13T21:27:15Z"></test-method>
    </class>
</test>
</suite>
</testng-results>
```

My current XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
  <Suite>
 <xsl:for-each select="testng-results/suite/test/class/test-method">
    <test>
       <xsl:attribute name="test_name">
          <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
       </xsl:attribute>
      <start_time>  </start_time>
    </test>
 </xsl:for-each>
  </Suite>
```

DESIRED OUTPUT.XML:

```
<Suite>
  <test test_name="ABC">
<start_time>2019-03-13 21:26:52.000 +0000 </start_time>
 </test>
<test test_name="XYZ">
<start_time>2019-03-13 21:26:52.000 +0000 </start_time>
 </test>
</Suite>
```

I have to get the date from the 'started-at' value and convert it to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z format to generate the output xml.

I have tried using format-dateTime function but it isn't supported by xsltproc (XSLT 1.0).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format a date in XML via XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500915/format-a-date-in-xml-via-xslt)

Comment: The input you show is not well-formed XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather quirky way without timezone adaption is the following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="test-method">
    <test test_name="{@name}">
      <start_time><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(@started-at,'T'),' ',substring-before(substring-after(@started-at,'T'),'Z'),'.000 +0000')" /></start_time>
    </test>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/testng-results">
    <Suite>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="suite/test/class/test-method" />
    </Suite>  
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Suite>
    <test test_name="ABC">
        <start_time>2019-03-13 21:26:52.000 +0000</start_time>
    </test>
    <test test_name="XYZ">
        <start_time>2019-03-13 21:27:15.000 +0000</start_time>
    </test>
</Suite>
```

P.S.:
The output also corrects an error in the desired output XML:
the 'XYZ' input is `2019-03-13T21:27:15Z` and not `2019-03-13T21:26:52Z`.

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT, all you want to do is replace the `T` with a space, and append `.000 +0000` instead of the `Z`:

```
<start_time>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(@started-at, 'TZ', ' ')"/>
    <xsl:text>.000 +0000</xsl:text>
</start_time>
```

Comment: Yep. It looks as simple as that. With `concat` it will be an XPath 1.0 only solution.