# how can i convert XLST date from 2020-12-30 to 20201230

Tags: xml, xslt

I get an XML file and try co convert it. Most of the fields I have done.

My code where I get the import is:

```html
<DeliveryDate>2020-11-03</DeliveryDate>
```

My XLST is:

```html
  <require><xsl:value-of select="PurchaseOrderLine/DeliveryDate"/></require>
```

The problem is that the format output is not good.

Input is `2020-12-31` and I need for output `20201231`

Comment: What is your XSLT version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format a date in XML via XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500915/format-a-date-in-xml-via-xslt)

Answer (score 0):

One quick way would be to use the replace function

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(PurchaseOrderLine/DeliveryDate,'-','')"/>
```

But you need XSLT 2.0 for that to work (<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"...)

For XLST 1.0 you need to create a template:

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$text = '' or $replace = ''or not($replace)" >
            <!-- Prevent this routine from hanging -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

And call it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="newtext">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="a" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="b" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Or try with translate:

```
<xsl:variable name="newtext" select="translate(PurchaseOrderLine/DeliveryDate,'-','')"/>
```

Comment: That's why I asked about the XSLT version in the comments above...

Comment: The template for XSLT 1.0 is overkill. `translate()` is fine. `translate()` actually works in all versions of XSLT so this should be the top choice.